# Disable auto-focus on text field (Chrome/Firefox)

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extensions

On some webpages, I need to scroll (read) and write in a text field at the same time. Unfortunately, every time I start typing (on any page), the page automatically jumps to the text field I'm typing in. Is there an option (javascript/extension/settings ideally for Chrome/Firefox)? I tried several javascripts but unfortunately none solved my problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24890920/prevent-default-scroll-to-element-for-input

Comment: If you tried some solutions, they should be listed in this question.